What do border officials do with my passport when I tell them that I'm entering as the spouse of an EU national?
Every time I enter or leave the Schengen zone with my EU spouse, I show our marriage certificate and state that I am entering as a family member. Border officials then do something to my passport. I am wondering what this is, and whether any record is made of my circumstances?
On one occasion, I was entering at Dover and hadn't realised that I was at the French border, until the border official stamped my passport. I explained and showed my marriage certificate. The official took my passport back, put 2 lines through the stamp, but also did something else at his computer. What was this?

FWIW the Schengen Borders Code specifies that someone entering the Schengen area in your circumstances should get a stamp.

By "do something to your passport", you mean put the passport in/on a reader?

Currently, in the Schengen Area, the only complete record of your entries or exits are the stamps in your passport (if any). This will change (for some cases) whenever the EES becomes active (originally planned for 2023, delayed multiple times, now planned for "sometime in 2025").
As pointed out in the comments, there can be records at the national level, but they are not necessarily consistent or systematic (I've been "waved through" more times than I can count just by vaguely showing my passport or ID, I think many times the officer didn't even touch it). They are however more likely for non-EU citizens.
What border officials generally do with a passport (details vary):

Make sure it looks genuine (physical inspection, check for alterations, check the security features...). May involve using an UV lamp to see some of the security features.
Use a passport reader to read the MRZ (the two lines at the bottom of the bio data page) and the RFID chip (for e-passports). This will give them the "real" data with is authenticated by crypto (a lot harder to forge than the bio data page, and a lot easier to check).
Look you up in the Schengen Information System (SIS) to see if you are forbidden from entry or other similar situations
Possibly compare what the bio data page says to what the RFID chip says.
Check that you look like the picture in the passport
When required, look for a valid visa
When required, check the visa in the Visa Information System (VIS) to see if the visa hasn't been annulled or cancelled, and see a few details about the application to ask questions about your stay.
When required, go through the passport to look for previous entry/exit stamps, and possibly count the days you were in and whether you still have days under the 90/180 rule, or under the rules of your visa, if appropriate.
When required, put a stamp, though there are many cases where they should and don't and vice-versa.

A lot of the lookups can be completely automated by just putting the passport on the reader: it will scan the MRZ, compute the key to access the RFID chip, read the RFID chip, perform authenticity checks, and get all the data required to perform the lookups in the SIS, VIS, etc, and display all the results on their screen (presumably with big bold red warnings when necessary).
Two diagonal lines in the corner of an entry or exit stamp invalidate that stamp. This is often done when you exit Schengen, but can't actually travel to the other country (for instance: at a land border: the other country refuses entry; for flights: the flight was cancelled and you come back into Schengen).
Not quite sure what they did on their computer. Possibly log the fact that they cancelled a stamp and why in case someone comes back to ask about it?

There is nothing in the Schengen acquis preventing countries from maintaining national systems recording additional information. The Schengen Borders code also provides for several other database lookups, including Interpol and national databases of stolen documents and national and Interpol databases to ascertain a person is not a threat to public policy, internal security, public health or international relations. Similarly, the SIS lookup will include a check against a list of stolen or invalid documents (and not only alerts on persons).

Some precision on the use of VIS: It could certainly be used to direct questioning and double-check some things but it doesn't record a whole lot of information on the application and that's not what's being retrieved first (cf. Schengen Borders code or VIS regulation). The main purpose is to prevent people from using someone else's passport, which is entirely possible when the passport is not biometric (rarer but still possible). People (very much including border guards) and even facial recognition systems (!) are quite bad at recognizing people from other ethnicities.

@Relaxed all of the facial recognition mistaken identity cases I've read about were ludicrous and involved police officers "trusting the system" when the two people (and the images of those people) clearly bore little resemblance to one another.  Of course, "media accounts of facial recognition failures" is rather the opposite of an unbiased sample, but it certainly leaves me with the impression that people are far better than facial recognition, perhaps excluding instances where the person is disguised and the computer can identify the facial geometry anyway.

@phoog That's a complex question, I tend to agree but I didn't mean to comment on the baseline level of accuracy. What I had in mind are evaluations from the NIST, especially NISTIR 8280 that suggest really breathtaking differences in the level of performance of these systems across demographics.

"the only records of entries or exits are the stamps in your passport (if any)" is technically not true - while the only Schengen-wide records are like that, many (most? all? I'm not sure, but definitely many) nations do record all the border crossings in their national records with great detail, which will also include the identification document data.

@Peteris If a nation records all border crossings in a national database, it would be a blatant violation of EU data protection laws. A government is not arbitrarily allowed to track a person's movements. For the same reason, also in the upcoming EES system, border crossings are only registered if it is necessary to keep a record of the time a person has spent in the Schengen area. The EES will contain no records of border crossings e.g. by EU/EEA citizens, residence permit holders or to a certain extent family members of EU/EEA citizens.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo no, it is not a violation of EU data protection laws; GDPR allows for national law asserting a state security interest. E.g. Latvian law https://likumi.lv/ta/en/en/id/201364-law-on-the-state-border-of-the-republic-of-latvia section 10.13  states "The information regarding the persons crossing the external border and travel documents thereof, as well as the vehicles driven by the persons when crossing the external border of the Republic of Latvia and documents of such vehicles shall be registered by the State Border Guard in the State information system." and it is done thus.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo We might wish it would be so but it's hard to see it as a blatant violation of EU data protection law. As a matter of fact, there is already some pretty extensive data collection through API systems. Not only does the GDPR allow it (“task carried out in the public interest or in the exercise of official authority”), it also gives cover for private businesses to assist (“necessary for compliance with a legal obligation to which the controller is subject”). There is also very little enforcement or push back from national DPOs or the EDPB.

Some countries are more comfortable with this type of open-ended surveillance than others but the GDPR is deliberately written not to interfere with it and when the authorities are intent on doing it, it doesn't provide much leverage to oppose it.

"the only complete record of your entries or exits are the stamps in your passport (if any)" – given that often there are no stamps, this means there is no complete record?

@Relaxed Exactly. Authorities may collect data if it is necessary for a 'task carried out ...', note the task. Authorities may collect data if it is necessary to do a specific job and not just on a 'nice to have' basis. The task requiring data to be stored in the EES is to keep track of how long persons have stayed in the Schengen area and since this task is only relevant for a certain set of persons, not all border crossings will be stored.

@Peteris Did you intentionally leave out the rest of the section you are linking to? 'The Cabinet shall determine the amount of the information to be included in the aforementioned system, the procedures for using it and the time periods for the storage thereof.' I don't speak Latvian and am not able to find the details of what is stored and what not. The law, if read fully and not only cherry-picked fragments, is not conclusive.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, that's explicitly the case for the EES, I covered that in my answer as well and I mostly expect anything done at the EU level to have a similarly well defined scope. But I don't think this notion of task places any serious restriction on national law enforcement.

Just to mention a recent example, the CNIL recently issued a decision on some French police files and merely complained about lack of information and outdated data, no objection in principle to the open-ended collection of extensive data covering people who have not been found guilty of anything, even witnesses. What's the “task” here beyond facilitating unspecified future investigations?

In particular, the CNIL was fine with repurposing data collected during criminal investigations for completely different purposes (background checks). That's a common pattern and I would be very surprised if the EU Commission gets involved or the EUCJ ever creates strict rules on that.


On one occasion, I was entering at Dover and hadn't realised that I was at the French border, until the border official stamped my passport. I explained and showed my marriage certificate. The official took my passport back, put 2 lines through the stamp, but also did something else at his computer. What was this?

This sound like a stamp cancellation. It would presumably be logged somewhere even if there is currently no way to share these data between Schengen member states.

A further question, if I may: when I exit the Schengen zone alone (showing my marriage certificate and copy of my spouse's passport to demonstrate on what basis I've been there) is it possible for the border guard to discover whether my spouse is currently in the Schengen zone or not?

@user49357 What do you have in mind? Something like a database? It's not the case but why would that be a concern? They can ask you obviously and take it from there, as they would for any material, all the way to calling her perhaps. Mostly, I would expect border guards to take your word for it but I wouldn't recommend lying either.

I've been in France for a few months with my spouse, then we unfortunately broke up. My partner has gone to the UK, but I'm still in France, essentially using my 90/180 Schengen days. When I next travel to the UK via Calais, I'm worried that I may have an issue at immigrations, since I will be travelling alone. So, I'm hoping to mitigate that.

@user49357 You should ask about that directly, in a separate question.
